# why does boolean use in JavaScript loop to escape loop?

Tags: javascript, boolean

**javascript**

As you saw in the below here use isFound variable and assign false when the condition is true when returning true and escape the loop but the question is when the condition is false then why use not false into the if the condition and how it works?

```
var laptop = ['asus', 'hp', 'lenovo'];
var find = 'accer';
var isFound = false;

for(var i = 0; i < laptop.length; i++) {
    if(laptop[i] == find) {
        console.log(laptop[i]);
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}


if(!isFound) {
    console.log('not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it in this way.

```
var laptop = ['asus', 'hp', 'lenovo'];
var find = 'accer';
var isFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < laptop.length && !isFound; i++) {
    isFound = laptop[i] === find;
}


if(!isFound) {
    console.log('not found');
}
```

or you can write it this way

```
var laptop = ['asus', 'hp', 'lenovo'];
var find = 'accer';
var isFound = laptop.some(function(item) {
    return item === find;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to find a specific laptop in predefined list of laptops.

At the beginning you assign value `false` to variable, because you don't know yet whether array store your wanted laptop.

```
var isFound = false;
```

At the end you compare value of variable. If is `true` then that means laptop is found. You can write like this:

```
if(isFound) {
    console.log('found');
} else {
    console.log('not found');
}
```

In the middle you check element by element if array contains wanted laptop. If you find such element you escape from loop because you don't need to check more values. You've already found what you are looking for.